# Django tried these URL patterns error 404

Tags: python, django

my site used to be ok but since I moved my website from my old server to new one suddenly my inner pages does not appear to work (my main page works ok) and I get 404 error with saying none of url patterns match the link.

I think I should change something due to changing the server but I don't know what.

this is my primary urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include('BestOfBrands.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
]
```

and this is my urls.py file which is in "BestOfBrands" Folder (my webapp folder):

```
urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<cg>[-\w]+)-Category/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^(?P<cg>[-\w]+)-Category/(?P<scg>[-\w]+)-SubCategory/(?P<s2cg>[-\w]+)-Brands/$', views.sub2category, name='sub2category'),
    url(r'^(?P<cg>[-\w]+)-Category/(?P<scg>[-\w]+)-SubCategory/(?P<s2cg>[-\w]+)-Brands/(?P<br>[-\w]+)/$', views.brand, name='brand'),
    url(r'^(?P<sub2category_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^(?P<brand_id>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.comment, name='comment'),
    url(r'^(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/replycomment/$', views.replycomment, name='replycomment'),
    url(r'^(?P<s2url>[-\w]+)/addbrand/$', views.addbrand, name='addbrand'),
    url(r'^(?P<usern>[-\w]+)-Profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^Change-Avatar/$', views.changeavatar, name='changeavatar'),
    url(r'^upload-avatar/$', views.uploadav, name='uploadav'),
    url(r'^(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/like/$', views.like, name='like'),
    url(r'^(?P<rcomment_id>[0-9]+)/likereply/$', views.likereply, name='likereply'),

]
```

Comment: what server do you use? nginx? if so, please add file with nginx configuration

Comment: You haven't said what url you are trying to go to.